# Extracting text before and after a certain phrase

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Consider the PDF file at the end of this message. I am trying to extract all the text before phrase Middle into var1 and all the text after it into var2. The problem is I do not know how to reference a starting/ending point for the page.

```
import PyPDF2
import re

myfile = "myPDF.pdf"
var1=""
var2=""
w = "MIDDLE"

with open(myfile, "rb") as file:
   reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)

   for x in range(len(reader.pages)):
      page = reader.pages[x]
      page_content = page.extract_text()
      if w in page_content:
         start = page_content.find(w)
         end= start + len(w)
         startVar2 = end + 1
         endVar2 = ?
         startVar1 = ?
         endVar1= start -1
         var1 = var1 + page_content[startVar1:endVar1]
         var2= var2 + page_content[startVar2:endVar2]
```

Could you let me know how to find  endVar2 and startVar1? and how to fill var1 and var2

Here is a sample file:

[image]

Comment: what if `w` appears more than once?

Comment: What you could do is consider `w` as a delimiter, then read the contents of the PDF into a list and `split` the list by `w`. That way, if `w` occurs more than once in the body of the PDF, you'll just end up with additional list items.

Comment: @Stuart For simplicity, let us start if it starts with one w in each page. Also, is your below answer assuming text has been read in a list? Can I do it without list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startVar1` will be 0, and `endVar2` will be `len(page_content)`. However, you do not even need to provide these parameters when slicing. You can do this instead:

```
var1 += page_content[:endVar1]
var2 += page_content[startVar2:]
```

And assuming `w` appears only once, you can also use `split` instead:

```
before, after = page_content.split(w)
var1 += before
var2 += after
```